# Laravel 5.1 create user won't insert added column?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, laravel-5.1

I have added a column for activation token in my users table and I want to add this random string when inserting new users.

So in my AuthController i have this:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'activation_token' => str_random(60),
    ]);
}
```

The user get's registered but the *activation_token* column remains empty???
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your `User` model look like?

Comment: Maybe your column activation_token has wrong type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent), you need to add this new field as a mass assignable field in your `User` model.

You are likely running in to trouble here as you haven't updated this, and as a result the `activation_token` is being excluded from the insert.

Try updating your mass assignable fields in your `User` model to something like this:

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'activation_token'];
```

Comment: Should I add here too `protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token', 'activation_token'];`

Comment: No need, simply add it to the protected $fillable and you'll be good as gold.